# $.get doesn't work in CrossRider in the background

Tags: browser-extension, crossrider

Is it possible to use jQuery's $.get, $.post or $.ajax in the background when using CrossRider? I tried but it seems not to work.

Comment: By the way, also in extension.js I tried to use $.get and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any Crossrider scope, we recommend using the Crossrider [appAPI.request](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.request) API methods to ensure browser & CORS compatibility. They are pretty similar to the jQuery counterparts and work for all browsers in all scope.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]